# How can I reduce the delay when locking the sceen on a MBPr?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-lock

So with a little research I found that <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> replaces the old <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd> on keyboards without eject keys. However I find I have to hold the keys longer for it to work, probably due to the power button having a delay to prevent accidental sleeping/shutdown.

What I'm looking to do is throw caution to the wind and remove that delay so I can simply hit the key combo not hold it, as I'm more likely to lock my station if it's quick than if I have to do it with purpose.

For reasons related to what system hooks get fired I need to use this method of locking the screen, so other methods aren't what I'm looking for.

It looks like I'll be forking on the [NoEjectDelay](https://github.com/tekezo/NoEjectDelay) source to make a NoPowerDelay variation if nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 1):

I use [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/) which comes with two actions that are instant: Lock Screen and Start Screen Saver (I have a password lock on resume from screen saver so they're more or less equivalent). Both take effect immediately and because [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/) is *awesome* the commands to remember them aren't some four-key, esoteric, multi-key combination I need to burn in to my memory.

I hit Cmd-Space to bring up LaunchBar. I type `loc` and I'm on the `Lock Screen` action. Similarly I can type `sta` to get to the `Start Screen Saver` action. I could, if I wanted, make these actions be the top actions for the single letter `l` and `s` if I wanted to mess with LaunchBar training, but this suffices.

They kick in instantly.

If you don't want to shell out for LaunchBar (but I tell you it's worth every penny to barely have to touch your mouse in the course of a work day) you can get similar pop-up and actions from [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) -- it has a [`lock` shortcut](http://support.alfredapp.com/cheatsheet) you can type to lock your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple app called "Salute".  Hitting Command - Control - Delete allows me to quickly enable screen saver and walk away from my work station.

Its a bit dated (it hasn't been updated recently), but it still works fine with 10.9.4 as I haven't had any trouble with it.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19689/salute

Comment: I love simple apps that solve one problem elegantly. Very nice.